# How to select folder in antd reactjs upload?

Tags: node.js, file-upload, antd

Is there a way to select only folders using antd upload? Please let us know if there is a way to handle this folder through antd.

Answer (score 0):

Use `directory` prop

```
directory: true
```

component

```
<Upload action="https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76" directory>
  <Button icon={<UploadOutlined />}>Upload Directory</Button>
</Upload>
```

Check the following examples

App.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { UploadOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { Button, Upload } from 'antd';

const App = () => (
  <Upload action="https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76" directory>
    <Button icon={<UploadOutlined />}>Upload Directory</Button>
  </Upload>
);
export default App;
```

OR

App.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { UploadOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { Button, message, Upload } from 'antd';

const props = {
  name: 'file',
  directory: true,   //Set directory to true
  action: 'https://www.mocky.io/v2/api12345',
  headers: {
    authorization: 'authorization-text',
  },
  onChange(info) {
    if (info.file.status !== 'uploading') {
      console.log(info.file, info.fileList);
    }
    if (info.file.status === 'done') {
      message.success(`${info.file.name} file uploaded successfully`);
    } else if (info.file.status === 'error') {
      message.error(`${info.file.name} file upload failed.`);
    }
  },
};
const App = () => (
  <Upload {...props}>
    <Button icon={<UploadOutlined />}>Click to Upload</Button>
  </Upload>
);
export default App;
```

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Reference:
[Antd Documentaion](https://ant.design/components/upload/#components-upload-demo-directory)